# CyberLink PowerDirector: Is it good for game footage?

Tags: video-editor, editing, post-production, intermediate

I have downloaded a free version of CyberLink PowerDirector but is it good for editing video game footage especially from video files from multi emulators? I just want to some of my videos 720p for Youtube but I do not want to upload the video directly from PowerDirector.

Answer (score 1):

I've used PowerDirector for a couple of years - it's primary strength is relative ease of use.  You won't find a ton of fancy here, but if that's okay for you, you should be fine.